# Multiple dropdown values to create SQL query PHP

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am currently tring to create a form wherein there is three dropdown option boxes and one submit button. All three of the dropdown boxes are populated from the database and I would like the selected options to be included into a new query and printed. *This example only shows one dropdown*

PHP Code

```
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect('', '', '', '');

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$course_dropdown ="";
$query_course = "SELECT * FROM course";
$result_course = mysqli_query($con,$query_course) or die(mysqli_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_course))
{
    $course_dropdown .= "<option value='{$row['CourseName']}'{$row['CourseName']}           </option>";
}
```

Above is the code that is used to create the dropdown lists

HTML

```
<form="index.php" method="post">
<select name="Course"><?php echo $course_dropdown; ?></select>
<input name="button" value="Submit" type="submit">
```

I am at a loss over what way to proceed, I have tried various different techniques but cannot come up with an answer.

Latest attempt

```
$course = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Course']);
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM course_module WHERE CourseName = $course");
```

this brought an error

*Notice: Undefined index: Course in C:\Users\seanin\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 33*

So have edited as suggested and stil have an error, may be missing something small.

```
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$course_dropdown ="";
$query_course = "SELECT * FROM course";
$result_course = mysqli_query($con,$query_course) or die(mysqli_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_course))
{
$course_dropdown .= "<option value='{$row['CourseName']}'>{$row['CourseName']}</option>";
} 

if ($_POST['button'] == 'Submit') {
$course = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Course']);
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM course_module WHERE CourseName = $course"); 
}
```

Still have this error

*Notice: Undefined index: button in C:\Users\seanin\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 30*

submit button issue

---

Nearly done, thanks for all the help so far.

What do I need to do to get the results and print them???

Comment: Don't just use `$_POST` variables into MySQL query's; escape them properly or better, use prepared statements.

Comment: you can escape value by mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['my_key'])

Comment: that was my last ditch attempt I have tried to delare "Course" as a variable but I recieve the error message "Course" not indexed.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: Course in C:\Users\seanin\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 33

Comment: @kirugan: The OP is using `mysqli_*` functions, so Seanin should use `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Comment: There's still an SQL injection vulnerability this way: if I set `$_POST['Course']` to `bla OR 1=1` I still get all fields. Use `Coursename = '$course'` instead. And which is line 33?

Comment: $course = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Course']); = 33

Comment: i get all the fields in th above code, I want to use the query to take the selected field and search for this query in the database

Comment: Is `Course` posted? You can test this by using `isset($_POST['Course'])`. And I meant all *records*.

Comment: first of all check isset($_POST['Course']) as mentioned by Marcel

Answer (score 2):

### Please read about [SQL injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). They can destroy your life.

I reckon that you are trying to access 'Course' in the following line and it is not defined:

```
$course = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Course']);
```

Are you able to submit the page? There is an error in your HTML form: `<form="index.php"` is not a valid HTML tag so you are not able to submit the page, that is if you posted the exact code you are using. Your form should be:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<select name="Course"><?php echo $course_dropdown; ?></select>
<input name="button" value="Submit" type="submit">
</form> <!-- and don't forget the closing tag -->
```

You can check whether the page was submitted or not by doing something like this:

```
if ($_POST['button'] == 'Submit') {
    $course = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Course']);
     // please note the missing single quotes, and please read the first line of my answer
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM course_module WHERE CourseName = '$course'");
}
```

There is also an invalid HTML syntax in the following line:

```
$course_dropdown .= "<option value='{$row['CourseName']}'{$row['CourseName']}           </option>";
```

The format for `<option>` is: `<option value="value">label</option>`.

Comment: Don't forget to use `htmlspecialchars` to prevent XSS when `echo`ing variables. And there's still an SQL injection vulnerability, surround `$count` by single quotes.

Comment: if ($_POST['button'] == 'Submit') {                                 is giving me bother                                               Notice: Undefined index: button in C:\Users\seanin\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 30

Comment: @SeaninLedgewood: Then `$_POST['button']` is not defined, perhaps due to your malformed markup. Change the `form` to the above mentioned syntax.

Comment: @SeaninLedgewood: Strange, you're not redirecting somewhere? Do you have an example page? Or a http://phpfiddle.org/?

Comment: im redirecting to the page im using, index.php. After I hit the submit button the error disappears

Comment: @SeaninLedgewood: Of course, because then your `$_POST` variables are defined. First check if they're defined by using `isset()`: `if (isset($_POST['button']) && $_POST['button'] == 'Submit') {`.

Comment: Yeah that did it @MarcelKorpel. Nearly done, thanks for all the help so far. What do I need to do to get the results and print them???

Comment: @SeaninLedgewood: Just echo the results like `echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['Course']);` (within the if-clause).

Comment: if (isset($_POST['button']) && $_POST['button'] == 'Submit') {
    $course = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Course']);
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM course_module WHERE CourseName = $course"); 
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) 
   
 
 else {
 
 printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
 
 }
 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 
 echo htmlspecialchars($row);
 }

Comment: @SeaninLedgewood: Please don't post code in comments, but edit your question. And you should still surround `$course` by single quotes to prevent SQL injection. And what do you want to say with this code? Does it work as expected? You probably want to output separate elements of `$row`.

Comment: Working correctly now, Thank You @MarcelKorpel you have been a great help and sorry about the code in comment, didnt know the rule.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your dropdown is not working is missing " > "
replace the line inside while loop with this

```
$course_dropdown .= "<option value='{$row['CourseName']}'>{$row['CourseName']}</option>";
```

Comment: Don't forget to use `htmlspecialchars` to prevent XSS when `echo`ing variables.

Comment: The dropdown is working 100% I want to take the selected item from the dropdown and run a query using the string selected